# AngularJS - Not working when adding ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0 ,user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>TESTS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<a href="#link">Testing angularjs routing</a>
<div ng-view>{{message}}</div>
<div ng-controller="TestController">{{message}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is app.js:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl:'index.html',
                controller: 'TestController'
            }).when('/link', {
                templateUrl:'link.html',
                controller:'LinkController'
            });
    });
testApp.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "INDEX";
});
testApp.controller('LinkController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.message = "LINK";
});
```

I'm trying to make routing work, but my link not clickabble at all, despite the fact that it looks like a normal link. Second message showing "INDEX", so I think problem in `ng-view`, because if I delete line with `ng-view` link become clickable again! I don't have a clue whats wrong!

Comment: can you add a plunker? I copied your code I am getting clickable link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is quite a few things wrong with your code.

Actually, it's not that your link don't work, it's that your crashing the browser by introducing an infinite loop. This is because you point your view to 'index.html' when the route is '/'.

So when you start, your loading index.html, which then loads index.html in it's ng-view, which then loads index.html in it's view, which then loads index.html... and so goes the wheel...

You also have some content in your ng-view, this will be replaced by the actual view you load.

Finally you using your TestController both on a view and in your index.html, which isn't illegal, but I doubt it would make much sense in any application... I could be wrong though.

So overall, it's sort of a mess. Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/MrdAKu86S3RoreQhO14H?p=preview

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl:'home.html',
                controller: 'TestController'
            }).when('/link', {
                templateUrl:'link.html',
                controller:'LinkController'
            });
    });
testApp.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "INDEX";
});
testApp.controller('LinkController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.message = "LINK";
});
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0 ,user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>TESTS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">

<a href="#/">Home</a>
<a href="#/link">Testing angularjs routing</a>

<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```